# Tapestry generates shape attribute on <a>

Tags: java, html, tapestry

I am using Tapestry 5.2.6, and I am trying to get rid of shape attributes on  tags.

Tapestry generates tag like this :

`<a shape="rect"...>`

I can't find anything online so if you have any idea how to ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was reported in Tapestry's JIRA and resolved in Tapestry 5.3.5. The offender was the SAX parser used, which automatically appends default values defined for HTML attributes in the DTD used. A check was then introduced in `org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.XMLTokenStream` class to "filter out attributes that are not present in the XML input stream, but were instead provided by DTD defaulting".

See the corresponding ticket for more details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-1976.

Unfortunately, in your case, there is no clean solution to fix that (assuming you have to work with Tapestry 5.2.6). The only way would be to make your own patch or fork of Tapestry 5.2.6 to report the correction...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I ll try to find a local fix for that. We have a lot of hacks and I don't think it would be easy to upgrade tapestry to 5.3.5.
I've seen the change on TemplateParserImpl and I'll try to patch this...